# Rails app to Heroku with existing images. Moving images to AWS bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm migrating my Rails apps to Heroku, but from what I read I should not save the images in the public/uploads folder.
I have figured out how to use the AWS buckets for saving new images, but how do I go about moving the existing images?

Also, is it absolutely necessary? 
I have read it everywhere, but even after a month of my apps being online I haven't seen my images deleted/moved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing files that are part of your repository will not be deleted.

But new images will get lost, because Heroku might reset the Dyno with a fresh version from the repository.

Comment: Thank you. Now everything makes sense.